# Write new line at the end of a file

Tags: python, numpy, text, newline

I am working with a numpy array in python. I want to print the array and its properties to a txt output. I want the text output to end with a blank line. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
# Create a text document of the output
with open("demo_numpy.txt","w") as text:
    text.write('\n'.join(map(str, [a,shape,size,itemsize,ndim,dtype])) + '\n')
```

And also:

```
# Create a text document of the output
with open("demo_numpy.txt","w") as text:
    text.write('\n'.join(map(str, [a,shape,size,itemsize,ndim,dtype])))
    text.write('\n')
```

However, when I open the file in GitHub desktop, I still get the indication that the last line of the file is "dtype"

Comment: Open your file in a proper editor and you'll see there is a new line at the end of the file (unless your GitHub handler doesn't remove trailing whitespace automatically before submitting it).

Comment: Thanks, @zwer I looked it up and I believe GitHub removes trailing whitespace, thats why I cant see the newline- but I believe its there. Question is- how can I see a blank line in a proper text editor anyway?

Comment: Typically, the editor's cursor will be able to move to the new line and if it supports displaying line numbers - it would show a line number for the new line as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using the Python 3.x print function, which automatically inserts a new line at the end of each print statement.

Here is the code:

```
with open("demo_numpy.txt","w") as text:    
    print(a, file = text)
    text.close()
```

- Note- apparently it is more appropriate to use the `print` function rather than `.write` when dealing with string values as opposed to binary files.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `"\n".join( ... )` you will get a string of the following form:

```
abc\ndef\nghi\nhjk
```

-- in other words, it won't end with `\n`.

If your code writes another `\n` then your string will be of the form

```
abc\ndef\nghi\nhjk\n
```

But that does not put a blank line at the end of your file because textfiles are supposed to have lines that end in `\n`. That is what the Posix standard says.

So you need *another* `\n` so that the last two lines of your file are

```
hjk\n
\n
```

Python will not choke if you ask it to read a textfile where the final trailing `\n` is missing. But it also won't treat a single trailing `\n` in a textfile as a blank line. It would not surprise me to learn that GitHub does likewise.

Comment: so is the first code line I posted in my question incorrect? Do I need to add another '\n' ? I think the first code actually works and it was just a GitHub issue of removing trailing whitespace.

Comment: I think both of the versions of your code do much the same thing. Both versions write a file that ends in a single `\n`. That does not, according to Posix rules, specify a blank line, because the trailing `\n` terminates the last line. You need a second `\n` to terminate the blank line you want. I refuse to believe that GitHub removes trailing whitespace. You don't have to take my word for it. Just put another `\n` and try it. It'll cost you fewer keystrokes than it took me to write this.